# Are there different standards to calculate the hex WEP key from an ASCII passphrase?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, hexadecimal, wep, passphrase

Are there different standards/methods to calculate a WEP key from a passphrase? Or why is it, that the 128 bit key generated on http://www.andrewscompanies.com/tools/wep.asp differ from the 128 bit key generated on http://www.wepkey.com/ ?

The keys generated and displayed on my router with dd-wrt 24 sp2 are the same as on wepkey.com but on another router (Zyxel) it works only with the one generated at andrwscompanies.com.

Why is this difference?

## Update

I have found [this site](http://www.corecoding.com/utilities/wep2hex.php) which converts a passphrase/password (same thing!) to

1. KEYs for non apple computers/networks: (104/128bit) (hashed key)
2. KEYs for apple networks or if the AP is an airport express

The **second** seems to be the one for **Zyxel** routers or access points (not only Apple). Also it seems that on **Fedora Linux** 21, the *Network Manager* wants the second key (or the ASCII passphrase), same as Apple and Zyxel computers.

Strangely I still can’t connect from my dd-wrt router (first key type) to my Zyxel router (second key type) although I used a ASCII passphrase on both. dd-wrt generated and displayed a hashed key from it. And the Zyxel should internally also use the hashed one, I think.

Any clues?

Comment: WEP, at any key length, has been broken for like 15 years, and devices have supported WPA2 for over a decade now. Do you really have ancient devices on your network that don't support WPA2? Is this a retrocomputing hobby project?

Comment: @Spiff Perhaps.  Or just for educational purposes.  Original poster gave no indication that he is trying to actually secure a network (in which case I would fully agree that WEP is very broken).  So I choose to follow the Stack Exchange guideline of giving original poster the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Spiff: I just want to understand it. And I could not find any references where my problem is explained. So if you could help me, I would really appreciate it.